# Getting error Room cannot verify the data integrity... even after adding fallbackToDestructiveMigration()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Why am I getting error `Room cannot verify the data integrity. Looks like you've changed schema but forgot to update the version number. You can simply fix this by increasing the version number.` even after adding `.fallbackToDestructiveMigration()` in Android?

```
private fun buildDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase {
        val appDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,
                AppDatabase::class.java,
                DATABASE_NAME
        )
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            appDatabase.fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
        }
        return appDatabase.build()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to increase the database **version**. You have to increase the database **version** after you update the database schemas.

```
@Database(
        entities = [SampleEntity::class],
        version = 1
)

abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary? I thought fallbackToDestructiveMigration() would drop old DB and create a new one but if we need to upgrade DB version it is like a workaround for database migration. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Realm DB does have a similar flag which drops old DB and creates a new one if required.